# Scene Builder 8.0 & Intelli. From one scene to another scene

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

How do I connect two scenes to each other with buttons/menuItems in Scene Builder?

I have done a new test-Project and tried what Hips showed me, but I get some errors. It's not exactly what Hips did so thats why I get errors but not him :-)

Main class.

```
package sample;

public class Main extends Application {

Stage window;
Scene mainScene, eventScene;
BorderPane mainLayout;
StackPane eventLayout;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    window = primaryStage;

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("main.fxml"));
    mainLayout = loader.load();
    MainController mainController = loader.getController();

    loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("event.fxml"));
    eventLayout = loader.load();
    EventController eventController = loader.getController();

    mainScene = new Scene(mainLayout);
    eventScene = new Scene(eventLayout);


    window.setScene(mainScene);
    window.setTitle("Test Project");
    window.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void setScene(Scene scene) {
    window.setScene(scene);
}
}
```

MainController.

```
package sample;


public class MainController {

private Scene eventScene;
private Main main;

public void setMain(Main main){
    this.main = main;
}
public void seteventScene(Scene eventScene) {
    this.eventScene = eventScene;
}

@FXML
public void switchScene() {
    main.setScene(eventScene);

}
}
```

main.FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<BorderPane fx:id="mainLayout" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.MainController">
<top>
  <VBox fx:id="vbox" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar">
          <menus>
            <Menu fx:id="fileMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
              <items>
                <MenuItem fx:id="newItem" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchScene" text="New..." />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="openItem" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open..." />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="saveItem" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save..." />
                    <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="exitItem" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Exit" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu fx:id="editMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu fx:id="helpMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
          </menus>
        </MenuBar>
     </children>
  </VBox>
</top>
</BorderPane>
```

EventController.

```
package sample;


public class EventController {

private Scene mainScene;
private Main main;

public void setMain(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}

public void setmainScene(Scene mainScene) {
    this.mainScene = mainScene;

}

@FXML
public void goBack() {
    main.setScene(mainScene);

}
}
```

event.FXML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.EventController" />
```

WHEN I click on the 'New...' MenuItem, this is the error I get.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at    com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.    java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.    java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sample.MainController.switchScene(MainController.java:21)
... 53 more
```

Comment: Almost nothing you say in this question makes any sense. "Here is the problem I don't understand. I use Scene Builder 8.0". How is using Scene Builder a problem? "How do I call the button?" What does "calling a button mean?" You call methods, not UI controls. And "I know that I need to create a method in the controller that tells that when I click on the button, I will be sent to the new scene". So, just do it? What's stopping you? Please clarify all this (a lot) and perhaps post some code to show what you are doing.

Comment: Just use Eclipse. You said it yourself, it works better for you. Use the best tools for the job, not what everyone else thinks you should be using. Eclipse + SceneBuilder is how I do all of my JavaFX projects.

Comment: 1.: Rename your .FXML files to .fxml  2.: Compare your .fxml files to mine - both miss the three lines of import statements. 3. Your programm will now run but the `switchScene` Method will not work because the `MainController.java` does not have reference to `eventScene` & `main` yet -> `NullpointerException` when calling `main.setScene(eventScene)`. Therefore you need to use the following statements in `Main.java` after declaring `eventScene = new Scene..` a) `MainController.setMain(this)`; b) `MainController.seteventScene(eventScene);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would consider to be a minimal example of how something like this can be achieved (in IntelliJ ;) ) - if you have any specific problems with IntelliJ feel free to ask.

Steps:

- Create a new Java Project
- Create two Controller Files
- Create two emtpy files and name them scene1.fxml and scene2.fxml
- Fill both .fxml   files with some elements using SceneBuilder and
  pass reference to their respective Controller. (in my case both
  scenes only consist ofa pane and a Button which `onAction` method is
  used to switch the scenes.
- Use the following code:

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    // Primary Stage
    Stage window;
    // Two scenes
    Scene scene1, scene2;
    // The panes are associated with the respective .fxml files
    private Pane pane1;
    private Pane pane2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            // Set the window as primary stage
            window = primaryStage;

            // Load the fxml files and their controllers
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("scene1.fxml"));
            pane1 = loader.load();
            Scene1Controller controller1 = loader.getController();

            loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("scene2.fxml"));
            pane2 = loader.load();
            Scene2Controller controller2 = loader.getController();

            // The scenes are based on what has been loaded from the .fxml files
            Scene scene1 = new Scene(pane1);
            Scene scene2 = new Scene(pane2);

            // Pass reference the each scenes controller
            controller1.setScene2(scene2);
            controller1.setMain(this);
            controller2.setScene1(scene1);
            controller2.setMain(this);

            //Display scene 1 at first
            window.setScene(scene1);
            window.setTitle("Scene!");
            window.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // used by the controllers to switch the scenes
    public void setScene(Scene scene){
        window.setScene(scene);
    }
}
```

Scene1Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class Scene1Controller {

    private Scene scene2;
    private Main main;

    public void setMain(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }
    public void setScene2(Scene scene2){
        this.scene2 = scene2;
    }
    // this method is called by clicking the button
    @FXML
    public void switchScene(){main.setScene(scene2);}
}
```

Scene2Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class Scene2Controller {

    private Scene scene1;
    private Main main;

    public void setMain(Main main){this.main = main;}
    public void setScene1(Scene scene1){this.scene1 = scene1;}
    // this method is called by clicking the button
    @FXML
    public void goBack(){main.setScene(scene1);}
}
```

scene1.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Scene1Controller">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="274.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchScene" text="Go to scene 2!" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

scene2.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Scene2Controller">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="194.0" layoutY="175.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goBack" text="Go back!" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Comment: Thank you Hips for a perfect example. Will look at it and try to understand it. I already seen the wrongdoing I have done.

Thank you once again.

Comment: Some clarification. In SceneBuilder - both buttons had their `onAction` set to call the methods `switchScene`/ `goBack`. There is no need to declare e.g. the Button a second time in the controller file. If we had some method which is supposed to change e.g. the buttons label we would have to add the following to the controller: `@FXML Button TheButtonsFXID;` and we could then reference it by e.g. calling `TheButtonsFXID.setText("New Name");`

Comment: I will update the main thread with some codes I used to do with your example. Instead of buttons I have MenuBar & MenuItems.
I did put the switchscene to the newItem in my project and I get some errors.

Comment: 1.: Rename your .FXML files to .fxml  2.: Compare your .fxml files to mine - both miss the three lines of import statements. 3. Your programm will now run but the `switchScene` Method will not work because the `MainController.java` does not have reference to `eventScene` & `main` yet -> `NullpointerException`. Therefore you need to use the following statements in `Main.java` after declaring `eventScene = new Scene..` a) `MainController.setMain(this)`; b) `MainController.seteventScene(eventScene);`

Comment: Ahh, I missed that, see it now. Thank you once again :)